# How to get Number of read and write events using Athana from Cloudtrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, amazon-athena

I've to get the read and write events from a Cloudtrail per day for n days. How do we partition the query to get a column where event type (read/write) is also specified?

Tried referring to the documentation, couldn't find anything there. Please help in writing the query.

i've created the table from the cloudtrail console directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'readonly' parameter is used for this. The events where 'read only' is false-> these are write events

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count , cast (from_iso8601_timestamp(eventtime) as date) as date , readonly
FROM "default"."sampleTable" 
WHERE cast (from_iso8601_timestamp(eventtime) as date) > current_date - interval '15' day
GROUP BY cast (from_iso8601_timestamp(eventtime) as date) , readonly ;
```